# How can I leave the tmux server running after the last session exists?

Tags: tmux

I'm trying to run tmux as a systemd user service `~/.config/systemd/user/tmux.service`. When I start the service with `systemd --user start tmux` and then run tmux from a terminal, it seems to correctly connect to the tmux server of the service.

However, when I close the last session, the tmux service stops. This is a problem because I want the tmux server to stay available for SSH clients. How do I prevent the tmux server from automatically stopping after the last session is closed?

```
[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=tmux new-session -s %u -d
ExecStop=tmux kill-session -t %u

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Solution:

```
[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=tmux new -s dummy -d
ExecStop=-tmux kill-server
Restart=on-success

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tmux has an option `exit-unattached` which says *If enabled, the server will exit when there are no attached clients*, which you can disable with

```
set-option -s exit-unattached off
```

in your `~/.tmux.conf`, but this doesn't seem to have any effect for me (on
or off), or I have misunderstood what it means.

You can ask systemd to restart your service on exit by adding the line

```
Restart=on-success
```

You also need to edit the `ExecStop` to prefix the command with `-` in order to ignore the failure of the `kill-session` command when restarting (because the server is no longer running by then).

```
ExecStop=-/usr/bin/tmux kill-session -t %u
```

Answer (score 0):

As of now, if you add this line to the `.tmux.conf` file, the server doesn't shut down when it has no sessions:

`set -g exit-empty off`